# Sourcetree not working with SSH key on Mac upgrade?

Tags: macos, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I've recently upgraded my Mac to 10.13, I have a sourcetree where it was working fine before the update, now after the update I am not able to push anything to my repositories, although it used to work before, anybody encounter this before?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Mac upgrade 10.13 involve some changes to OpenSSH policy, you can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html

You will need to add the identity to the list from terminal:

run:

```
ssh-add -l
```

you will get "No identity message", you should add you SSH key, run:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Check that the change is made by running the first command again, then you should see that the key is add.

Now you all set and Sourcetree will push normally.